# Swift Two Tab Bars shown and not sure why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Does anybody know why I might have these stacked tab bar?

[image]

I don't see where this would be in any of my view controllers and what code i would even look for.  If guidance on what would even generate this would help.  It's a fixed bar on the bottom and I'm trying to remove it.  I am not sure when it started to show up here anyways.  It serves no purpose for me. It also shows up on each of the tabs when I click on each of them.

Comment: Is that a tab bar or a toolbar? Check the attributes inspector for your viewcontroller. What is the `Bottom Bar` drop-down set to?

Comment: The height certainly looks like less than that of a tab bar (could be partially overlapping, though). I don't think an extra tab bar could just "slip in" unless you nest two tab bar controllers or something (not sure that's even _possible_).

Comment: It's all through a TabBar View controller.  I have a navigation controller embedded at each tab.  The bottom bar dropDown in each of the view controllers for each of he view controllers is "Inferred"

Answer (score 0):

You are using a searchBar, if you want just one bar you would have to move the searchBar to the top of the screen

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out what I did wrong.  At some point, I clicked "shows toolbar" in the navigation controller that was embedded in the tab view controller.  When I unchecked this the second toolbar went away.

Thanks for everyones help.